# How to find range in which a number falls, from given list of numbers?

Tags: functions, list-manipulation, operators

How can one find the range in which a number falls, from given list of numbers?

```
f[x_, list_List] := ???
(*
Return {a,b} where
a & b belongs to list
{a,b} forms shortest possible interval which match condition
if a<=x<=b {a,b}
if x <= a {-∞,a}
if x >= b {b,∞}
*)
```

`f` Should also consider outer ranges $-\infty$   and $\infty $

Comment: And what do you want to happen with `f` if `x` is an element of `list`?

Comment: it should return two ranges then

Comment: And when there is only one element in the list , and if it is x then it should return `{{-∞,x},{x,∞}}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Interpolation

I propose using `Interpolation`.

```
list = Prime ~Array~ 3000;
intf = Interpolation[
         {list, Range@Length@list}\[Transpose],
         InterpolationOrder -> 0
       ];
```

Then, for point `x`:

```
x = 12225.4;

Which[
 x < First@list , {-∞, First@list},
 x > Last@list  , {Last@list, ∞},
 True           , list[[#-1 ;; #]]& @ intf @ x
]
```

> ```
> {12211, 12227}
> ```

---

This could all be done inside `Interpolation` as well:

```
intf2 =
  Interpolation[
    Join[
      {{First@list, {-∞, 2}}},
      Thread[{Rest@list, Partition[list, 2, 1]}],
      {{Last@list + 1, {Last@list, ∞}}}
    ],
    InterpolationOrder -> 0
  ];

intf2[12225.4]
```

> ```
> {12211, 12227}
> ```

---

### Ordering

The method above was written from the perspective of repeated searching within the same list, and as noted in the comments it is assumed that the input list is sorted and free of duplicates.

If these assumptions do not hold other methods become appealing.  After a review of others answers seeking inspiration, including those by kglr, celtschk and Leonid, I find Leonid's use of [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html) to have great promise but his function is hobbled by the comparatively slow function [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html).  We can replace it with a use of [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html).

- This function requires a sorted list as input, but including the overhead of `Sort` I still find it faster than other methods I tried such as a separate application of `Ordering` in an earlier revision of this answer.
- I use an explicit `Subtract` [for performance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40927/121).

Code:

```
seekOrdered[x_, list_] /; x < First @ list := {-∞, First @ list}

seekOrdered[x_, list_] /; x >= Last @ list := {Last @ list, ∞}

seekOrdered[x_, list_] := 
  list[[# ;; # + 1]] & @@ Ordering[UnitStep @ Subtract[x, list], -1]
```

Here are comparative timings including Leonid's `getInterval`, celtschk's function, and a variation of kglr's `interval2` using `Replace` rather than `ReplaceList` to return a single interval (in the case of ambiguous matches) for somewhat better performance. (Credit to [Ali Hashmi](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27331/ali-hashmi) for noting this.)

The various functions I am comparing take slightly different interpretations of the end point behavior requested therefore output does not precisely match.  It should be possible to change the behavior of my function with a bit of tinkering should that be required for a particular application.

The other functions as I will be timing them:

```
getInterval[ints_List, num_] := 
  Position[UnitStep[ints - num], 1, 1, 
    1] /. {{{1}} -> {-Infinity, First@ints}, {} -> {Last@ints, Infinity}, {{n_}} :> 
     ints[[n - 1 ;; n]]};

celtsF[x_, list_List] := 
 Module[{pos = Last@Ordering@Ordering[Append[list, x]]}, 
  Which[pos == 1, {-Infinity, First@list}, 
   pos == Length[list] + 1, {Last@list, Infinity}, True, list[[{pos - 1, pos}]]]]

interval2fast[x_, list_List] := 
 Replace[#, {___, a_, x, b_, ___} :> {a, b}] &@
  Join[{-Infinity}, Sort[Join[list, {x}]], {Infinity}]
```

Benchmark 1:

```
list = Prime ~Array~ 3000;

xs = RandomInteger[{-100, 30000}, 5000];

interval2fast[#, list] & /@ xs;  // RepeatedTiming // First
getInterval[list, #] & /@ xs;    // RepeatedTiming // First
celtsF[#, list] & /@ xs;         // RepeatedTiming // First
seekOrdered[#, list] & /@ xs;    // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 1.25
>
> 0.5890
>
> 0.224
>
> 0.114

With a packed input list:

```
list = Developer`ToPackedArray @ list;

(* other code the same *)
```

> 1.16
>
> 0.5370
>
> 0.129
>
> 0.0689

With Reals rather than Integers for the search elements:

```
xs = RandomReal[{-100, 30000}, 5000];

(* other code the same *)
```

> 1.54
>
> 0.5674
>
> 0.855
>
> 0.0981

With Reals rather than Integers for the list:

```
list = Sort @ RandomReal[27000, 3000];

(* other code the same *)
```

> 1.88
>
> 0.552
>
> 0.129
>
> 0.0895

Of course for this repeated application `Interpolation` is faster still:

```
intf2 /@ xs; // RepeatedTiming // First // Quiet
```

> 0.0112

Comment: Yet another non-obvious gem +1

Comment: This method requires pre-sorted input data without duplicates. For an arbitrary list you need to pre-process the list with `DeleteDuplicates@Sort` or `Union`. `Interpolation` gives error messages when input data is unsorted or contains duplicates.

Comment: @kguler Indeed.  Thank you for stating that.  I made assumptions on the meaning and structure of a "given list of numbers."

Answer (score 11):

You can make use of `BinCounts`.  I think this is a very simple to understand solution because `BinCounts` does almost exactly what you need already.

```
f[x_, list_List] :=
 Module[{bins},
  bins = Join[{-Infinity}, Sort[list], {Infinity}];
  First@Pick[Partition[bins, 2, 1], BinCounts[{x}, {bins}], 1]
 ]
```

But it won't give you two intervals if the number is part of both.  Of course it's very easy to put in an extra check and include this feature if you need it, but I just wanted to show the concept now.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the list `list` is already ordered, the following should answer your question:

```
f[x_,list_List]:=
  Module[{pos=Last@Ordering@Ordering[Append[list,x]]},
    Which[pos==1,{-Infinity,First@list},
          pos==Length[list]+1,{Last@list,Infinity},
          True,list[[{pos-1,pos}]]]]
```

Comment: I just largely recreated this method without intending to copy your answer. +1 of course, and sorry for not noticing this answer long ago.  My code performs somewhat faster because I used the second parameter of `Ordering` thereby avoiding a full second pass.  My current answer is written to include the sort explicitly, but for a direct comparison see the code in [this revision](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/435/6).

Answer (score 6):

My favorite:

```
 interval[x_,list_List]:=ReplaceList[Append[Prepend[Sort@list, -Infinity], 
        Infinity], {___, a_, b_, ___} /; (a <= x <= b) :> {a, b}]
```

EDIT: Much faster if we eliminate the condition checking as follows:

```
 interval2[x_, list_List] := ReplaceList[#, {___, a_, x, b_, ___} :> {a, b}  ] &@
   Join[{-Infinity}, Sort[Join[list, {x}]], {Infinity}]
```

Comment: This is clever, but it is going to be quite inefficient.  This is 10,000X slower than `InterpolatingFunction` on the data in my answer.  This may or may not matter, but it should be noted.

Comment: Mr.Wizard, i agree. Both your `InterpolatingFunction` method and `Pick`-based method in my other answer (after removing `Sort` from the definition) are uncomparably faster than `ReplaceList`. However, `ReplaceList` and pattern-based approaches often have this hard-to-resist  simplicity.

Comment: I yield; +1 for simplicity.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I believe Using `Replace` rather than `ReplaceList` will yield much much faster results especially if the list is very long. I tried with the example posted by you for a list of 30000 primes and a value of 1250.4 the speed is 120X slower with `ReplaceList` with conditional checking on

Comment: @kglr nevertheless your second method is extremely fast !! + 1

Comment: @kglr my bad, `Replace` is as bad with conditional checks for very large lists and when the value is located close to the end of the list.

Comment: @AliHashmi At a glance I cannot see why kglr chose `ReplaceList` over `Replace`; the use of the former prevents early exit behavior and given the sort I don't think multiple matches make sense?  Also, thank you for commenting as I don't think I ever saw kglr's `interval2` which is a very nice method.  I wonder if it can be bettered using `Ordering`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard actually i am amazed. With the second method `interval2` I literally see no difference in performance whether I use `ReplaceList` or `Replace`.

Comment: @AliHashmi and kglr, please see my updated answer.

Comment: @AliHashmi I just checked again and I find `ReplaceList` marginally slower on the test currently at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @AliHashmi actually on a separate point I just realized that my update is bogus because I still assumed a sorted list.  Now I have to see if I can fix that without looking too silly. ;-p

Comment: @Mr.Wizard looking forward to the update :)

Comment: @AliHashmi I think I got it right this time.  Since I have your eyes on it would you mind checking for me?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yours is ~ 3 times faster. Tried with a `RandomSample` of 3000000 primes ! wow

Comment: @AliHashmi I took a break for dinner but now I am playing with this problem again.  Contrary to an earlier statement `ReplaceList` does produce different output, e.g. `interval2[2, {1, 2, 3}]` gives `{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}`, but that is not the output requested in the Question.  Perhaps kglr will comment when he is surprised to see this long chain of comments on an old post.

Comment: @AliHashmi I made yet another major revision to my answer.  It turns out that (IMHO) Leonid's code was the better starting point, but it needs a little help to be competitive.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, @AliHashimi looks like i should replace `ReplaceList` with `Replace`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another version:

```
ClearAll[getInterval];
getInterval[ints_List, num_] :=
 Position[UnitStep[ints - num], 1, 1, 1] /.
  {
    {{1}} -> { -Infinity, First@ints},
    {} -> {Last@ints, Infinity},
    {{n_}} :> ints[[n - 1 ;; n]]
  };
```

Comment: Now this is really fast !! wish there was a +2 here

Answer (score 5):

```
intervals[x_, list_List] :=
  Cases[
    Partition[Flatten[{-Infinity, Union[list], Infinity}], 2, 1]
  , {l_, u_} /; l <= x <= u
  ]
```

Use cases:

```
In[53]:= intervals[3, Range[10]]
Out[53]= {{2,3},{3,4}}

In[54]:= intervals[3, 2 * Range[10]]
Out[54]= {{2,4}}

intervals[-3, Range[10]]
Out[55]= {{-∞,2}}

In[56]:= intervals[999, Range[10]]
Out[56]= {{10,∞}}

In[58]:= intervals[37, {13,8,1,28,87,14,61,20,91,92,37,93,76,83,32}]
Out[58]= {{32,37},{37,61}}
```

Comment: While working on this question I was surprised to find that out `Sort[{4, 3, 2, 1, -∞, ∞}]` yielded `{1, 2, 3, 4, -∞, ∞}` (and `Union` too).

Comment: That's because `Sort[]` uses `OrderedQ[]` by default. Try `Sort[{4, 3, 2, 1, -∞, ∞}, Less]`.

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, *Combinatorica* has the function [`BinarySearch[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/ref/BinarySearch.html) implemented. The code in the package is attributed to Paul Abbott. What follows is a modification of the routine that gives results in the format desired by the OP:

```
bisect[k_?NumericQ, l_List] := 
 Block[{n = Length[l], lo, mid, hi, el},
   {lo, hi} = {1, n};
   While[lo <= hi,
    If[(el = l[[mid = Quotient[lo + hi, 2]]]) === k,
     Which[
      mid == 1,
      Return[{{-Infinity, First[l]}, Take[l, 2]}],
      mid == n,
      Return[{Take[l, -2], {Last[l], Infinity}}],
      True,
      Return[Partition[Take[l, mid + {-1, 1}], 2, 1]]]];
    If[el > k, hi = mid - 1, lo = mid + 1]
    ];
   Which[
    lo == 1,
    Return[{-Infinity, First[l]}],
    lo == n + 1,
    Return[{Last[l], Infinity}],
    True,
    Return[l[[{lo - 1, lo}]]]
    ]
   ] /; VectorQ[l, NumericQ]
```

I'll leave to you how to handle the case of the singleton list.

Answer (score 3):

Among many alternatives you can use something like

```
glblub1[x_, data_List] := Pick[#, IntervalMemberQ[Interval@#, x] & /@ #]& @
                              ( Partition[#, 2, 1]& @
                                Append[Prepend[Sort@data, -Infinity], Infinity])
```

or

```
glblub2[x_, data_List] := Pick[#, (#1 <= x <= #2) & @@@ #]& @ 
                              ( Partition[#, 2, 1]& @
                                Append[Prepend[Sort@data, -Infinity], Infinity])
```

If `x` is a member of the list and you wish to return `x` rather than two intervals containing `x` use as

```
Intersection@@glblub1[x,data]
Intersection@@glblub2[x,data]
```

or just redefine the two functions by prefixing both with `Intersection@@`.

Answer (score 3):

WReach's answer prompted me to write another answer:

```
intervals[x_?NumericQ, list_List] := 
 With[{sl = Sort[Flatten[{-Infinity, list, Infinity}], LessEqual]},
   sl[[{#, # + 1}]] & /@ 
    Flatten[Position[
      Times @@@ Partition[Sign[x - sl], 2, 1], -1 | 0]]] /; 
  VectorQ[list, NumericQ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list is sorted, the easiest approach i can think of is as follows:

```
rangeFind[list_, y_] := First@Select[Join[{{-Infinity, First@list}},
Partition[list, 2, 1], {{Last@list + 1, Infinity}}], #[[1]] <= y <= #[[2]] &]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
rangeFind[list_, val_] := With[{ranges = Partition[Sort@list, 2, 1]}, 
ranges[[# + 1]] &@LengthWhile[ranges, ! (#[[1]] <= val <= #[[2]]) &]]
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard and 4.5 x faster than my approach :p `Ordering` is nicer. Lesson learnt

Answer (score 0):

Adding a [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) solution.

With

```
SeedRandom[1213]
data = RandomReal[{-200, 200}, 30]
```

and

```
f[x_, list_] :=
 Piecewise[{#, x <= Last@#} & /@
   Partition[Join[{-∞}, Sort@list, {∞}], 2, 1]]
```

Then

```
f[#, data] & /@ {-400, 0, 400}
```

> ```
> {{-∞,-198.392},{-15.7702,3.96342},{196.004,∞}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
f[x_?NumericQ, list_List] :=
 Module[
  {list2 = Join[list, {-Infinity, Infinity}]},
  {Max[Select[list, # <= x &]],
   Min[Select[list2, # >= x &]]}]

SeedRandom[1]

lis = RandomReal[1, 5]

(*  {0.817389, 0.11142, 0.789526, 0.187803, 0.241361}  *)

{#, f[#, lis]} & /@ Range[0, 1, .1] // Grid
```

[image]