# Better way to select all array indexes matching predicate?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I'd like to select (offset) indexes of a number of array points, that match a selection criteria.  I can do this by creating a Table of all the coordinates, and then selecting all the values:

```
data = Array[ RandomInteger[1] &, {4, 4}]
{wx, wy} = data // Dimensions ;
t = Flatten[
  Table[ {x - wx/2, y - wy/2, data[[x]][[y]]}, {x, 1, wx}, {y, 1,
    wy}], 1]
Select[ t, #[[3]] == 1 &]
```

This resulted in the respective values:

```
{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}}
{{-1, -1, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {-1, 2, 1}, {0, -1, 1}, {0, 0,
  0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 2,
  0}, {2, -1, 1}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 2, 1}}
{{-1, -1, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {-1, 2, 1}, {0, -1, 1}, {0, 2,
  1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, -1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}
```

However, my real data is big (800x800) and sparse.  This method creates a big data set and then throws most of it away.  What is a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is your data a `SparseArray`?  Can you make it a `SparseArray`?

Comment: BTW you can write `RandomInteger[1, {4,4}]` and `data[[x,y]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider:

```
{wx, wy} = {4, 4};

SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomInteger[1, {wx, wy}]

{#1 - wx/2, #2 - wy/2, data[[##]]} & @@@ Position[data, 1]
```

> ```
> {{-1, -1, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 2, 1}, {0, 2, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}
> ```

For better performance you can use `SparseArray` to directly compute the list of positions, then use the `"NonzeroPositions"` Property to extract them.  For example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
m = RandomInteger[5, {10, 10}];
```

Optimized code to find the positions of all elements equal to four:

```
sa = SparseArray[Unitize @ Subtract[m, 4], Automatic, 1];

pos = sa["NonzeroPositions"]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 6}, {2, 7}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}, {3, 7},
>  {3, 9}, {5, 5}, {6, 8}, {7, 4}, {8, 5}, {9, 6}, {10, 3}}
> ```

(The long form of `Subtract` is used because [peculiarly it is faster](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40927/121).)

You could then operate on these positions as I did above.  Better still, set all non-selection elements in the array to the same value, and use that as the background of the SparseArray, then also use the `"NonzeroValues"` Property as well.  For example let's select all elements in the interval $[2, 4]$:

```
{wx, wy} = {14, 20};

SeedRandom[1]
m = RandomInteger[99, {wx, wy}];

sa = SparseArray[Clip[m, {2, 4}, {0, 0}]];

pos = sa["NonzeroPositions"]
val = sa["NonzeroValues"]
```

> ```
> {{1, 5}, {1, 13}, {3, 5}, {3, 9}, {4, 14}, {9, 5}, {9, 20}, {11, 10}, {14, 16}}
>
> {3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2}
> ```

We can then transform positions using fast vector operations:

```
pos2 = (pos\[Transpose] - {wx/2, wy/2})\[Transpose]  (* this looks much nicer in a Notebook *)
```

> ```
> {{-6, -5}, {-6, 3}, {-4, -5}, {-4, -1}, {-3, 4}, {2, -5}, {2, 10}, {4, 0}, {7, 6}}
> ```

And combine with the values using `Join`, which does not unpack:

```
Join[pos2, val ~Partition~ 1, 2]

% // Developer`PackedArrayQ
```

> ```
> {{-6, -5, 3}, {-6, 3, 4}, {-4, -5, 4}, {-4, -1, 2}, {-3, 4, 3},
>  {2, -5, 2}, {2, 10, 2}, {4, 0, 2}, {7, 6, 2}}
>
> True
> ```

Note that using `SparseArray` properties with packed/packable data is *much* faster than using ArrayRules:

```
{wx, wy} = {14000, 20000};

SeedRandom[1]
m = RandomInteger[99, {wx, wy}];

sa = SparseArray[Clip[m, {2, 4}, {0, 0}]];

Timing[
 pos = sa["NonzeroPositions"];
 val = sa["NonzeroValues"];
]

Timing[
 rules = Most @ ArrayRules[sa];
]
```

> ```
> {0.0088, Null}
>
> {4.649, Null}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Here's some sparse sample data of size 800 by 800:

```
am = AdjacencyMatrix@RandomGraph[{800, 1000}];
data = am.am;
data -= DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal[data];
```

It contains 1s and 2s (other than zeros).

Let's find the positions of 2s:

```
Cases[Most@ArrayRules[data], HoldPattern[position_ -> 2] :> position]
```

These positions can be easily offset after they're found.

You're probably looking something more like this variation:

```
Cases[Most@ArrayRules[data], HoldPattern[position_ -> value_ /; value == 2] :> Append[position, value]]
```

This approach is best when you have sparse arrays to work with.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, depending on how dense the input matrix is, `Position` may perform better than the `Cases`/ `ArrayRules` combination:

```
am = AdjacencyMatrix@RandomGraph[{800, 1000}];
data = am.am;
data -= DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal[data];

ClearSystemCache[];
out1 = Cases[Most@ArrayRules[data], HoldPattern[position_ -> 2] :> position]; // Timing
(* {0.015625,Null} *)
ClearSystemCache[];
out2 = Position[Normal@data, 2, {2}]; // Timing
(* {0.03125,Null} *)
Length@out1/(800  800) // N
(* 0.0000375 *)
Sort@out1 == Sort@out2
(* True *)
```

For a denser matrix

```
am = AdjacencyMatrix@RandomGraph[{800, 10000}];
data = am.am;
data -= DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal[data];
ClearSystemCache[];
out1 = Cases[Most@ArrayRules[data], HoldPattern[position_ -> 2] :> position]; // Timing
(* {0.3125,Null} *)
ClearSystemCache[];
out2 = Position[Normal@data, 2, {2}]; // Timing
(* {0.046875,Null} *)
Length@out1/(800  800) // N
(* 0.140584375` *)
Sort@out1 == Sort@out2 
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use functions `Sow` and `Reap`

```
t = Reap[
  Do[
   If[data[[x]][[y]] == 1, Sow[{x - wx/2, y - wy/2, data[[x]][[y]]}]],
   {x, 1, wx}, {y, 1, wy}
   ]
  ]
t = t[[2,1]]
```