# Why does Mathematica appear to change the head of certain expressions?

Tags: evaluation, core-language

I don't know if the question trivial or not (if so I will delete it), but here is what I have:

I know that

```
x x
(*  x^2  *)
```

Looking at the full form gives

```
FullForm[Times[x, x]]
(* Power[x, 2] *)
```

It is clear that the `Times` head has been changed to `Power` head. 
I just wonder how does this happen. Can I control this behavior to stop this conversion between heads?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use this function to see that the conversion is not made during parsing:

```
parseString[s_String, prep : (True | False) : True] := 
  FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[s, prep]]

parseString["x x"]
```

> ```
> {BoxData[RowBox[{"x", "x"}]], StandardForm}
> ```

We can use this to see that the conversion does not take place while converting boxes to [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StandardForm.html):

```
ToExpression[RowBox[{"x", "x"}], StandardForm, HoldComplete] // FullForm
```

> ```
> HoldComplete[Times[x,x]]
> ```

We can see that the rule is applied as part of the normal evaluation sequence:

```
Times[x, x] // TracePrint
```

> x x
>
> Times
>
> x
>
> x
>
> (x^2)
>
> Power
>
> x
>
> 2

You cannot generally "stop this conversion" but you can temporarily disable the rules for `Times` using [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Block.html):

```
Block[{Times},
 ToString[x x]
]
```

> ```
> "Times[x, x]"
> ```

You can also [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Hold.html) or [`HoldComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldComplete.html) expressions and apply your own rules.

Neither of these methods lets `Times` otherwise behave as desired.  I have [lamented this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40927/121) problem myself with regard to `Subtract` and `Divide` as the "equivalent" forms they are converted into are neither equivalent nor as fast.

Comment: Mr.Wizard, do you have new insight in the problem with the short forms you linked to? You said in one of the comments you might post a partial solution at some point. I'm sure many people would be interested (including me)!

Comment: @sebhofer I wish I did.  I tried a few things and I didn't come up with anything I wanted to use.  However it's been a long time and I didn't try too hard as I was hoping someone else had a better idea.

Answer (score 4):

*Mathematica* embraces the notion of canonical form. Internally it wants all expressions to be reduced to their canonical forms.

`Times[x, x]` is not a canonical form, so it gets reduced to `Power[x, 2]`, which is.

I share Mr.Wizard's occasional frustration over the choices of canon made by Wolfram Research, but I think it is far too late to expect any change. So grin and bear it, as we say here in the US.

Comment: thank you for the explanation and for the advice I am smiling right now while bearing the fact :)