# Colorize Grayscale Image

Tags: programming, image-processing, color, performance-tuning

I have a grayscale image that contains two objects. The grayscale pixel values can be divided into three intervals where two of them represent objects and the third represents the background. The background is almost uniform, with pixel values close to 0.5. The other two intervals are [.2,.4] and [.55,.73].

I developed a function to colorize this image. It works fine, but I'm looking for ways to make it run faster. Any suggestions?

```
colorizeFunction[image_, α_, β_, γ_, θ_] :=
  Module[{data, newdata, red, green, blue, datared, datagreen, 
   datablue, newdatared, newdatagreen, newdatablue}, (
   {red, green, blue} = ColorSeparate[image];
   datared = ImageData[red];
   datagreen = ImageData[green];
   datablue = ImageData[blue];
   newdatared = datared /. x_ /; α <= x <= β -> 1;
   newdatagreen = datagreen /. x_ /; α <= x <= β -> 0;
   newdatablue = datablue /. x_ /; α <= x <= β -> 0;
   newdatared = newdatared /. x_ /; γ <= x <= θ -> 0;
   newdatagreen = newdatagreen /. x_ /; γ <= x <= θ -> 1;
   newdatablue = newdatablue /. x_ /; γ <= x <= θ -> 0;
   ColorCombine[{Image[newdatared], Image[newdatagreen], 
     Image[newdatablue]}, "RGB"]
   )]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key is [`Binarize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Binarize.html) but I couldn't figure out a good way to overlay colored parts on a grayscale image so this is rather hackish.  At least it is quite a bit faster than your method:

```
colorize2[image_, α_, β_, γ_, θ_] :=
 ColorCombine[{
    ImageSubtract[ImageAdd[img, #1], #2],
    ImageSubtract[ImageAdd[img, #2], #1], 
    ImageSubtract[img, ##]}] &[
      Binarize[image, {α, β}], 
      Binarize[image, {γ, θ}]
    ]
```

Test:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}] ~ColorConvert~ "Grayscale";

colorize2[img, 0.2, 0.4, 0.55, 0.73]
```

[image]

---

*Edit:* I figured out [`HighlightImage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HighlightImage.html) but it is an order of magnitude slower than what I wrote myself:

```
colorize3[image_, α_, β_, γ_, θ_] := Fold[
  HighlightImage[#, Binarize[image, #2[[1]]],
    Method -> "Solid", "HighlightColor" -> #2[[2]]] &,
  image,
  {{{α, β}, Red}, {{γ, θ}, Green}}
]
```

---

*Edit #2:* Another method, perhaps more pleasing in style, but twice as slow as `colorize2`:

```
extract[i_][x_, y_, c_] := # ~ImageMultiply~ c ~SetAlphaChannel~ # & @ Binarize[i, {x, y}]

colorize4[image_, α_, β_, γ_, θ_] := 
  Fold[ImageCompose, image, extract[image] @@@ {{α, β, Red}, {γ, θ, Green}}]
```

---

*Edit #3:* A slightly faster but less clean version of `colorize2` leveraging [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40927/121):

```
colorize2fast[image_, α_, β_, γ_, θ_] :=
 ColorCombine[
   Image /@ {Subtract[#3 + #, #2],
             Subtract[#3 + #2, #],
             Subtract[#3, # + #2]},
 ] & @@ ImageData /@
         {Binarize[image, {α, β}],
          Binarize[image, {γ, θ}],
          image}
```

Comment: colorize2[] is ~ 13 faster than colorizeFunction[]. But the color is not uniform. For example the green pixels haven't the same values like {a,b,c}.

Comment: But colorize2[] is 1.04 faster than colorize3[]. perfect

Comment: @Developer2000 Could you give me an example of the non-uniform colors?  I am seeing e.g. `{{0., 1., 0.}, {0., 1., 0.}, {0., 1., 0.}, {0., 1., 0.}, ...` in the upper left corner of the image in my answer.

Comment: @Developer2000 Your comment that `colorize2` is only 13 times faster than the original made me look at things again.  It was my mistake to use `Timing` rather than `AbsoluteTiming`, but correcting that I still measure about 45X faster in 10.0.1 under Windows.  Which version are you running?

Comment: @Developer2000 I added `colorize2fast` which tests somewhat faster still on my machine.  Please try it.

Comment: color2fast is 3.27 fatser than color2. I use Mathematica 10.0.1 on Mac os X 10.9,core i7, Ram=8G. But, on my image, the color is not uniform. I will check

Comment: @Developer2000 Thanks for the report.

Comment: about 15x faster than  my `ImageApply` :(.

Answer (score 5):

something like this?

```
  ImageApply[ If[ # < .5, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}] &, 
       ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Gray21"}] ]
```

[image]

another example, looking again I guess you want to leave gray outside the specified ranges.

```
 ImageApply[Piecewise[{ 
     {{1, 0, 0}, .1 < # < .3},
     {{0, 0, 1}, .6 < # < .7},
     {{#, #, #}, True}}] &, ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Boat"}]]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response. I edit my question to be more clear.