# Division by zero is slow

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

Suppose I have two arrays of data, which I want to divide:

```
n = 1000;
a = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {n, n}];
b = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {n, n}];
First @ AbsoluteTiming @ (a/b)
```

> `0.637064`

But suppose that two thirds of the values are actually zero.  I'd want the ones dividing by zero to just remain zero.

```
mask = RandomChoice[{0, 0, 1}, {n, n}];
c = mask a;
d = mask b;
First @ AbsoluteTiming @ Quiet[c/d /. Indeterminate -> 0]
```

> `8.568857`

Now it has become very slow.  How can we speed this up?

**Edit:** Thanks for all the answers guys.  Below are some timings:

[image: timings]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SparseArray` can help, given the size and nature of the `mask`.  It's slightly faster to convert `c` and `d` to sparse arrays than to convert `a` and `b`.

```
mask = SparseArray@RandomChoice[{0, 0, 1}, {n, n}];

First@AbsoluteTiming[
 c = mask a;
 d = mask b;
 Quiet[foo2 = Block[{Indeterminate = 0}, SparseArray[c] / SparseArray[d]]]
 ]
(*
  0.151565
*)
```

Compare:

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  c = mask a;
  d = mask b;
  foo1 = Quiet[c/d /. Indeterminate -> 0]
  ]
(*
  6.492534
*)

foo2 == foo1
(*
  True
*)
```

Comment: @kguler I'm not sure why you deleted your `Block` trick, which I've used because it's faster than any other trick I've tried.  But let me know if there's a problem.  My use of `SparseArray` is a significant difference, but `Replace` does not work on it.  `Block` and `Map` were the only tools I had, and `Map was way too slow.

Comment: The trick will fail when `c` and `d` are using different `mask`s. (`Block` won't help because the `FullForm` of the output of `ComplexInfinity` generated by `1/0` etc. is `DirectedInfinity[]`.) Anyway, it's the fastest method for OP's specific example so far.

Comment: @xzczd Actually it seems very odd to have different masks.  In the OP's Q, it's clear that `Indeterminate` is to go to `0`. `1/0` does not become `Indeterminate` and there is no indication that `ComplexInfinity` should become `0`.  (I decided it probably should not.)

Comment: I like this answer the best.  It's a bit wordy, but clear what it is doing.  It's fast and flexible (if you want to do more than a simple divide).  It's not quite so fast if you want to do a `Normal` afterwards - about the same speed as the case with no zeroes.

Comment: Michael, just saw your comment (somehow i think `@name` mechanism is broken; i don't get pinged when mentioned in comments). The only reason i deleted my answer was I forgot to refresh the kernel  in a long/crowded mma session and got confused with conflicting results:)  (+1)

Comment: @kguler The at-name only works if you've posted a comment already.  I put it there just in case you saw this answer.  I knew you wouldn't get pinged by it, but I didn't know how to ping you.

Answer (score 8):

Simply turn all the `0/0`s into `0/1`s:

```
ans2 = c/(1 - Sign@d + d); // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.7630000, Null}
> ```

The above answer only works for specific example in the question i.e. it only handles positive lists and identical `mask`. For more general cases one can use:

```
n = 1000;
(* a and b contain non-positive elements now *)
origin := RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, {n, n}]
a = origin; b = origin;

(* c and d now use different masks *)    
mask := RandomChoice[{0, 0, 1}, {n, n}];
c = mask a; d = mask b;

ans2 = With[{s = Unitize@d}, Divide[s c, 1 - s + d]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.606000, Null}
> ```

Notice that [`Divide` is faster than `/`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40927/1871).

Comment: The best general answer so far IMHO.

Comment: Note that you can use `Unitize@d` in place of `Abs@Sign@d`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It makes sense that one might know beforehand that `0/0` ought to be `0` - in any case, `Indeterminate -> 0` is specified in the question.  The question leaves open what should happen to a result like `1/0` or `ComplexInfinity`.  One might want infinity, zero or a different result, such as a maximum value.  The general answer here effectively takes the union of the masks, which is a plausible (even common) use-case.  But I think one ought to be careful in stating which generalized problem it is a solution to. - +1 long before now. :)

Comment: Clever and fast, but I'm going to wonder what the heck it is doing when I come back to read the code a few months later.  Comments are for the weak.

Comment: @wxffles I think the most probable obstacle for one to understand the code is unfamiliarity with `Unitize` and vectorization :) …OK, I've added a bit explanation, just a bit though.

Answer (score 7):

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable];
f@__ := 0
f[a_, b_] /; b != 0 := a/b
First@AbsoluteTiming[f[c, d];]
```

**Edit**

On the same spirit, this is 50% faster:

```
SetAttributes[g, Listable];
g[_, 0] := 0
g[a_, b_] := Divide[a, b]
First@AbsoluteTiming[g[c, d];]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not particularly fast.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Unfortunately, it looks a lot like your code too... what have you done to belisarius! :P

Comment: @rm-rf I am taking over the world one syntax at a time. :p

Answer (score 2):

```
c/(d /. (0 | 0. -> Infinity));
```

Answer (score 2):

For the given example where no values in `b` are zero before the `mask` one can use:

```
Divide[mask*a, b]
```

Note the use of explicit `Divide` for [optimum performance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40927/why-are-numeric-division-and-subtraction-not-handled-better-in-mathematica).  Timings:

```
(* your data *)

(r1 = Quiet[c/d /. Indeterminate -> 0]); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(r2 = Divide[mask*a, b]);                // AbsoluteTiming // First

r1 == r2
```

> ```
> 4.578262
>
> 0.212012
>
> True
> ```

For the general problem I cannot beat xzczd's method.

Comment: +! I keep forgetting about `Divide`....

Comment: How about `Divide[maskb maska a, b]`?  It's only a bit faster.  If all factors are converted to `SparseArray`, it's  faster still, even including the conversion time.