# Choose between `Apply` and `Map`

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, functional-style, function-comparison

Even though this might be too general question(or not answerable), I want to get some advice here. I apologize in advance if it is not a relevant question.

I frequently have to process large list of data(nested) and have to apply a function to each element. For example, consider the following simplified contrived example.

Given a list,

```
 dat = {RandomReal[], RandomReal[]} & /@ Range@(10^6);
```

I want to apply a function. There might be several ways to achieve the same behavior, especially I usually find `Map` and `Apply` are good ways to go, i.e.,

```
{t, d} = #[[1]]/#[[2]] & /@ dat  // Timing;
{t2, d2} = #1/#2 & @@@ dat  // Timing;
{t3, d3} = Divide @@@ dat  // Timing;
```

In this particular example, there exists a built-in function `Divide`,  so I added the third one as a reference. 
The times spent in each line in my machine were `{t, t2, t3} == {0.500000, 6.187500, 1.875000}`. Therefore, using `Map` might be the most efficient way in this case.

However, in my real world codes, there are some cases that the version of `Apply` is much faster, and thus I usually tend to try several versions and choose the best one when the performance really matters. But it would be very nice if I could get a hunch on which one is better in advance. Is there any general guideline for this problem?

Comment: I think for this particular example, it's because `Map` returns a packed array. 
``In[8]:= Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {d, d2, d3}

Out[8]= {True, False, False}``

Comment: faster still for this case : `Divide @@ Transpose[dat] `

Comment: @ChipHurst, It sounds plausible. So does `@@@` usuall suppress the formation of the `PackedArray`?

Comment: @george2079 Thank you. Your version is much faster than the others.

Comment: @Sungmin I'm not sure. Though simple examples such as ``Developer`PackedArrayQ[#& @@@ dat]`` seem to unpack arrays.

Comment: @ChipHurst Maybe that suggests I should use `Map` when I am working with `PackedArray`. Thank you.

Comment: Slightly related: [40927](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40927/5478), because of function you use. Related: [46248](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46248/5478), due to the topic.

Comment: Make use of Listability. The reason that `Divide @@ Transpose[dat]` is so much faster is because you can divide entire lists rather than have to loop through all elements of the list

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Could you be more specific? Are you suggesting something similar to `Function[{x, y}, x/y, {Listable}]`? Could you suggest explicit form of function for this example?

Comment: No. I'm suggesting reading up on listability. You do not need to map elements from lists onto a function that divides them. Try `Range[10]/Range[11,20,1]` or `Range[10]^Range[11, 20, 1]`

Comment: confirm the packedarray issue: if you set `dat[[1]]=={1,1}` (forcing a non-packed array), the first `Map` approach becomes much slower than the others.

Comment: @george2079 Even though this might be too abrupt, it seems that I should consider `Map` if I am using a `PackedArray`  and use `Apply` otherwise :).

Comment: Not necessarily because the fastest method above was using `Apply`: `Divide @@ Transpose[dat]`. But generally speaking because it unpacks lists it will slow things down

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Thank you for clarifying it.

Comment: You can also speed up your random number generation using `dat = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^6, 2}];`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Odd that this question had no answers until today.  Anyway, *the performance of various methods*, unsurprisingly, *depends on the details of their applications*.  Generally speaking there are several layers of possible performance levels in *Mathematica* including optimized C libraries, sometimes with automatic parallelism, functions compiled within *Mathematica* either manually or automatically, operations fully internal to the pattern-matching engine, and high level rule-based expression transformation.  (This is by no means an exhaustive list.)  The more efficient a layer you are able to apply to your program, the faster it will run.

The high level rule language is highly flexible but not generally fast.  An example:

```
dat = RandomReal[1, {1*^6, 2}];

Replace[dat, {a_, b_} :> Divide[a, b], {1}] // Timing // First // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.612035, 0.592804}
> ```

This is (or should be) effectively equivalent to this `Map` application, though `Map` is slower for a reason I do not understand:

```
divide[{a_, b_}] := Divide[a, b]

divide /@ dat // AbsoluteTiming // First // Timing
```

> ```
> {1.014007, 1.020058}
> ```

Both methods above require both a pattern matching operation and application of `Divide` for each pair of numbers.  Using `Apply` at level one and `Divide` avoids the first operation and is faster:

```
Divide @@@ dat // AbsoluteTiming // First // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.405603, 0.401023}
> ```

This, still requires a separate high level evaluation for each pair of numbers however.  But `Map` has a possible trick in store: **automatic compilation**.  For this to be applicable, the data need to be packed or packable and the function must be compilable.  In this case `dat` is both packable and packed, as output by `RandomReal`, but `divide` is not automatically compilable.  If instead we use:

```
divide2 = Divide[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &;

divide2 /@ dat // AbsoluteTiming // First // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.093601, 0.098006}
> ```

This *is* automatically compilable and we see an order of magnitude improvement.  Here, there is only the initial high level evaluation of `Map` with its automatic compilation, then all the pairs are processed in lower-level code.  This, at least by default, is running in the *Mathematica* virtual machine, rather than low level C code, so it is not yet optimal.  `Divide` is (*presumably*) written in C but if it is to be fast, we need to avoid repeated high level evaluation of the function and instead pass it all the data at once.  It bears the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) attribute and is specifically optimized for this case.  To do that, we can use `Transpose` as mentioned in the comments, below the question:

```
Divide @@ Transpose[dat] // AbsoluteTiming // First // Timing
```

> ```
> {0., 0.022001}
> ```

This is so fast, we need larger data to get an accurate estimate:

```
big = RandomReal[1, {1*^8, 2}];

(big2 = Transpose[big]) // AbsoluteTiming // First // Timing

Divide @@ big2          // AbsoluteTiming // First // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.358802, 0.428024}
>
> {0.249602, 0.589034}
> ```

This is another order of magnitude faster than the auto-compiled `Map` operation.  We can see the breakdown in the time between `Transpose` and `Divide` operations.  There is very little high-level evaluation here; nearly all of the computation is done at the compiled library level.  This is enabled by packed input to functions specifically optimized to handle it.  (`Apply` in `@@ dat` unpacks but only one level; `Divide` is still given two packed lists as input.)

In each of the examples above, I used `Divide` rather than `/` for consistency due to this issue:

- [Why are numeric division and subtraction not handled better in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40927/121)

Answer (score 6):

The problem isn't choosing whether **Map**, **Apply**, etc., are faster, but how to decide how much work you're asking Mathematica to do.  I like the following method:

**Trace** shows you every detail of every step of a calculation; if you apply **Trace** to each of your calculations, you'll see that there are simply more steps required for some methods than the others.  So:

```
dat = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}
Trace[#[[1]]/#[[2]] & /@ dat]
(*
{(#1[[1]]/#1[[2]] &)[{a, b}], (#1[[1]]/#1[[2]] &)[{c, 
    d}], (#1[[1]]/#1[[2]] &)[{e, f}]} etc ...

*)
```

The output from **Trace** quickly gets impenetrable, so I use **ByteCount** as a rough and ready way of estimating how complex it is --- **ByteCount** is one way of counting how many steps there were, and how complicated they were.

So, combining the steps:

```
dat = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}
ByteCount@Trace[#[[1]]/#[[2]] & /@ dat]  (* 9600 bytes *)
ByteCount@Trace[#1/#2 & @@@ dat]         (* 4800 bytes *)
ByteCount@Trace[Divide @@@ dat]          (* 2672 bytes *)
```

You can also try the same exercise with the other versions of "dat" you'll see that the amount of time to complete a calculation is loosely related to the size of Trace.

```
dat = {RandomReal[], RandomReal[]} & /@ Range@(10^6);
ByteCount@Trace[#[[1]]/#[[2]] & /@ dat]  (* 40 001 264 bytes *)
ByteCount@Trace[#1/#2 & @@@ dat]         (* 1 648 001 304 bytes *)
ByteCount@Trace[Divide @@@ dat]          (* 416 001 000 bytes *)
```

Note that the first method is very efficient when working on the packed array.  If you "unpack" the array, the first method loses its efficiency:

```
dat = {RandomReal[], RandomReal[]} & /@ Range@(10^6);
dat[[1, 1]] = {1, 1};
ByteCount@Trace[#[[1]]/#[[2]] & /@ dat]  (* 3 152 003 128 bytes *)
```

p.s. never ever forget **Transpose**... for packed data, this is the fastest method:

```
With[{t = Transpose[dat]}, t[[1]]/t[[2]]]
```