# DateListPlot of multiple time series with data values and legend appearing as the cursor moves over ploted lines

Tags: plotting, graphics, date-and-time, time-series

This is very similar to my [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65606/listlineplot-of-multiple-series-with-data-value-and-legend-appearing-as-the-curs). I want to use `"DateListPlot"` to visualize multiple time series (n) and see data values and legend as I move the cursor over plotted lines. To begin with, I have the following codes (preferable n > 2):

```
Stock1 = FinancialData["NVDA", "Close", {{2017, 1, 1}, Now}];
Stock2 = FinancialData["QQQ", "Close", {{2017, 1, 1}, Now}];
DateListPlot[{Stock1, Stock2},PlotLegends -> {"NVDA Price", "QQQ 
 Price"},PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

It produces the graph but does not show the data points as I move my mouse along the plotted lines. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about [TradingChart](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TradingChart.html?q=TradingChart): `TradingChart[{"GE", {{2017, 1, 1}, Now}}]`?

Comment: Any improvement on my answer is most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) to create a plot that displays the values via [`MousePosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MousePosition.html).

[image: plot tracker]

I use [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html) to speed up finding the values in the series.

```
nearStock1 = Nearest[First@# -> # & /@ MapAt[AbsoluteTime, {All, 1}]@Stock1];
nearStock2 = Nearest[First@# -> # & /@ MapAt[AbsoluteTime, {All, 1}]@Stock2];
```

The plot's `Epilog` has a bit of formatting in it but it is nothing out of the ordinary.

```
DateListPlot[{Stock1, Stock2},
 PlotLegends -> {"NVDA Price", "QQQ Price"},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green},
 Epilog ->
  Dynamic@Module[{s1, s2},
    With[{pos = MousePosition[{"Graphics", DateListPlot}, {0, 0}]},
     s1 = First@nearStock1@First@pos;
     s2 = First@nearStock2@First@pos;
     {
      Thin, LightGray, InfiniteLine[pos, {0, 1}],
      PointSize[Large],
      Darker@Red, Point[s1],
      Darker@Green, Point[s2],
      Inset[
       Grid[
        MapAt[NumberForm[#, {5, 2}] &, {All, 2}]@
         MapAt[DateString[#, "ISODate"] &, {All, 1}]@{s1, s2},
        ItemStyle -> {{Automatic}, Darker /@ {Red, Green}},
        Alignment -> {{Automatic, Decimal}, {Automatic}}
        ],
       Scaled[{.02, .98}],
       Scaled[{0, 1}]
       ]
      }
     ]]
  ]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ Edmund, thank you for your time and answer. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified form of Edmund's solution:

```
DateListPlot[...]~Tooltip~Dynamic[{DateString[#[[1]], "ISODate"], #[[2]]} &@
   MousePosition["Graphics"]]
```