# Efficient way to sum all the primes below $N$ million in Mathematica

Tags: programming, algorithm

Today, I saw a problem described as below:

> Sum all `primes` below $N$ million

At the beginning, I feel it is rather simple to calculate it in *Mathematica* enviroment. unfortuately, I failed >__< (Here, I assume $N=10$)

***Trail 1***

```
Total@(Prime /@ Range[PrimePi[10^9]])
```

> General::nomem: The current computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation.

***Trail 2(Clumsy method)***

```
PrimePi[10^9](*50847534*)

step0 = Total@(Prime /@ Range[1, 10^7]);
step1 = Total@(Prime /@ Range[10^7, 2*10^7]);
step2 = Total@(Prime /@ Range[2*10^7, 3*10^7]);
step3 = Total@(Prime /@ Range[3*10^7, 4*10^7]);
step4 = Total@(Prime /@ Range[4*10^7, 50847534]);

res=
 step0 + step1 + step2 + step3 + step4 - Total@(Prime /@ {10^7, 2 10^7, 3 10^7, 4 10^7})
```

> ```
> 24739512092254535
> ```

Then I discoved a most efficient algorithm by Google

It is derived from similar algorithms for [counting primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function). The advantage is that there is no need to find all the primes to find their sum.

> Let $S(v,p)$ be the sum of integers in the range $2$ to $v$ that remain after sieving with all primes smaller or equal than $p$. That is $S(v,p)$ is the sum of integers up to $v$ that are either prime or the product of primes larger than $p$.
>
> $S(v, p)$ is equal to $S(v, p-1)$ if $p$ is not prime or $v$ is smaller than $p^2$. Otherwise ($p$ prime, $p^2 \leq v)\quad  S(v,p)$ can be computed from $S(v,p-1)$ by finding the sum of integers that are removed while sieving with $p$. An integer is removed in this step if it is the product of $p$ with another integer that has no divisor smaller than $p$. This can be expressed as
>
> $S(v,p) = S(v, p-1) - p (S(\lfloor v/p \rfloor, p-1) - S(p-1,p-1))$

Here,we need to compute $S(n,\sqrt n)$

> `Dynamic programming` can be used to implement this.

**Performance**

(A implementation can be found [here](http://luochen1990.me/try_coffee?#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))

> [image]

#### Question

- Is it possible to implement this algorithm in *Mathematica* by `Dynamic programming`?
- It is my first time to hear `Dynamic programming`, so I'd like to know what's is `Dynamic programming`?

Comment: FWIW, `Total[Prime /@ Range[PrimePi[10^9]]]` evaluates to `24739512092254535` — i.e. the same as your trial 2 result. The computation took a few minutes, and the peak kernel memory usage was about 4.7GB.

Comment: Approximation to 5-7 digits on the OP's values for `n`: `sumP = #*RiemannR[#] - (NIntegrate[RiemannR[x], {x, 2, #}]) &`.  It takes about `0.15` sec. on all (those) inputs.

Comment: [Dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) (DP) is, "a method for solving a complex problem by breaking it down into a collection of simpler subproblems."  As an example, solving the problem of making $n$ cents with the fewest number of coins has a DP algorithm where we find the number of ways to make each amount $\leq n$ using only pennies, then with pennies and nickels, then wtih dimes, etc.  Each solution is a simple function of two of the previously calculated solutions.  (I learned about DP while competing in USACO, a good way to build your algorithm skills.)

Comment: @2012rcampion,OK, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a direct translation of the code you linked:

```
Module[{n = 10^9, r, v, p, sp},
  r = Floor@Sqrt@n;
  v = Table[Floor@(n/i), {i, 1, r}] ~Join~ Range[-1 + Floor@(n/r), 1, -1];
  ClearAll[s];
  Scan[(s[#] = (# (# + 1))/2 - 1) &, v];
  For[p = 2, p <= r, ++p,
    If[s[p] > s[p - 1],
     Scan[(s[#] -= p (s[Floor[#/p]] - s[p - 1])) &, TakeWhile[v, # >= p^2 &]];
     ]
    ]~Monitor~p;
  s[n]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{22.134213, 24739512092254535}`

For the "dynamic programming" bit, we are using a function `s` to store values that we have calculated.  You could try a `?s` afterwards to see what's there.

Comment: You'll get a nice speed bump changing `TakeWhile...` to `Pick[v, UnitStep@Subtract[v, p^2], 1]`. +1 on translating that.

Answer (score 10):

No time for a full answer but with four cores in [`ParallelSum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelSum.html):

```
ParallelSum[Prime@i, {i, PrimePi[10^9]}] // AbsoluteTiming

MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> {55.366167, 24739512092254535}
>
> 108337144
> ```

Pretty fast and very little RAM required.

---

A modest refactoring of wxffles's code in a more native style including rasher's suggestion:

```
Module[{n = 10^9, r, v, s},
  r = Floor@Sqrt@n;
  v = Quotient[n, Range[r]] ~Join~ Range[Quotient[n, r] - 1, 1, -1];
  s = AssociationThread[v -> (v (v + 1))/2 - 1];
  Do[
    With[{sp1 = s[p - 1]},
     If[s[p] > sp1, 
      Scan[(s[#] -= p Subtract[s[# ~Quotient~ p], sp1]) &, 
        Pick[v, UnitStep @ Subtract[v, p^2], 1]];]],
    {p, 2, r}
  ] ~Monitor~ p;
  s[n]
] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {13.229757, 24739512092254535}
> ```

Explicit `Subtract` is used for performance; see:

- [Why are numeric division and subtraction not handled better in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40927/121)

Comment: +1 This is why you are the Wiz. Man, my answer is huge compared to yours and not nearly as good.  LOL!

Answer (score 6):

[Dan Fortunato](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/21475/dan-fortunato) and I made use of `Compile` for this one.

```
index = Compile[{{p, _Integer}, {r, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}},
  If[p <= r,
    r + Quotient[n, r] - p,
    Quotient[n, p]
  ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  Parallelization -> True,
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
];

PrimeSum = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
  Module[{r = Floor[Sqrt[n]], V, S, p = 2, ind = 0, i = 1, v = 0},
    V = Quotient[n, Range[r]] ~Join~ Range[Quotient[n, r] - 1, 1, -1];
    S = Quotient[#(#+1), 2] - 1 & /@ V;
    For[p = 2, p <= r, ++p, 
      If[S[[index[p, r, n]]] > S[[index[p-1, r, n]]],
        i = 1;
        While[(v = V[[i++]]) >= p^2,
          ind = index[v, r, n];
          S[[ind]] -= p (S[[index[Quotient[v, p], r, n]]] - S[[index[p-1, r, n]]])
        ];
      ]
    ];
    First[S]
  ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  Parallelization -> True,
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed",
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}
];
```

Here are some timings

```
Column[AbsoluteTiming[PrimeSum[10^#]]& /@ Range[11]]
```

> ```
> {0.000075, 17}
> {6.*10^-6, 1060}
> {0.000017, 76127}
> {0.000069, 5736396}
> {0.000319, 454396537}
> {0.001524, 37550402023}
> {0.007245, 3203324994356}
> {0.036089, 279209790387276}
> {0.176848, 24739512092254535}
> {0.897198, 2220822432581729238}
> {4.595891, -1447107067060386762}
> ```

Notice the final answer is negative. This is because the answer is larger than the largest machine integer `(2^63 - 1)`, which we can verify [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20primes%20%3C%3D%2010%5E11).

**Edit:** Note the correct answer for `PrimeSum[10^11]` is `201467077743744681014`.

Comment: @ShutaoTang Please see my revision. I just edited the code to be much faster.

Answer (score 2):

I have two efficiency increase approaches using existing functions.

1. Distribute the load evenly over the available kernels in parallel. This has gains in speed but memory usage will be about the same.
2. Distribute the load evenly over time. This significantly reduces memory usage but increases time.

Capture the number of primes we want to sum.

```
nn = PrimePi[10^9];
```

For option 1 I take the told number of primes and divide them evenly over the number of kernels.  I first `LaunchKernels` to be certain all are ready and `$KernelCount` is correct.  If you are going for option 2 then you may replace `$KernelCount` with any positive integer of your choice.

```
LaunchKernels[];
intPart = First@IntegerPartitions[nn, {$KernelCount}, {Floor[nn/$KernelCount],
  Ceiling[nn/$KernelCount]}];
intPart = Rest@FoldList[
 Function[{running, next}, {running[[2]] + 1, next + running[[2]]}], {0, 0}, intPart];
```

I restrict `IntegerPartitions` to only select partitions of length equal to the number of kernels (or parts specified if option 2) available (I have 4 kernels) and fix the usable values to create evenly sized partitions. I then use `FoldList` to get the partition intervals.

**For option 1**

```
DistributeDefinitions[intPart];
Plus @@ Parallelize[Total@Prime@Range[Sequence @@ #] & /@ intPart, 
 Method -> "CoarsestGrained"] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {43.8049, 24739512092254535} *)
```

Before I execute in parallel `intPart` has to be shared across the kernels with `DistributeDefinitions`.  Then I can execute with `Parallelize` and instruct that it should be broken up into as many pieces as I have kernels (and I have ensured that I have equal pieces to number of kernels).

**For option 2**

```
Plus @@ (Total@Prime@Range[Sequence @@ #] & /@ intPart) // AbsoluteTiming
(* {112.644, 24739512092254535} *)
```

I have the range broken into evenly sized intervals and now just map the `Total` over each.  This executes each item of the map in serial and so uses less memory overall.

**The original bulk version**

```
Total[Prime /@ Range[PrimePi[nn]]] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {113.591, 24739512092254535} *)
```

**Summary**

It takes 44 seconds to execute in parallel on my machine whereas the two non-parallelised versions take about 113 seconds.  Each of the 4 kernels in option 1 used about 1.1GB of memory at the same time; so 4.4GB at once. However, option 2 used about 1.1GB (1/4th of option 1 while using 4 intervals over the range) for its entire execution but took 1.5 times as long to complete. Now the original bulk version uses the same amount of memory as option 1 but takes as long as option 2.

What is interesting is that option 2 and the bulk version take about the same time because each term is independent and the operator (`Plus`) is commutative. So with a little partitioning of the range you can get your result with your current memory restrictions.

Hope this helps.