# Why are there significant differences in efficiency between various instances of ParallelSum?

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, prime-numbers

These four commands

```
ParallelSum[Prime[i]^2, {i, 1, 10000} ] // AbsoluteTiming
ParallelSum[Prime[i] + Prime[i + 1], {i, 1, 10000} ] // AbsoluteTiming
ParallelSum[ Prime[i] + Prime[i + 1] + Prime[i + 2], {i, 1,  10000} ] // 
AbsoluteTiming
ParallelSum[Prime[i] + Prime[i + 1] + Prime[i + 2] + Prime[i + 3], {i, 1, 
10000} ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

gives out nearly the same time.

but when I change  10000 to  100000

```
ParallelSum[Prime[i]^2, {i, 1, 100000} ] // AbsoluteTiming
ParallelSum[Prime[i] + Prime[i + 1], {i, 1, 100000} ] // AbsoluteTiming
ParallelSum[
Prime[i] + Prime[i + 1] + Prime[i + 2], {i, 1,  100000} ] // AbsoluteTiming
ParallelSum[Prime[i] + Prime[i + 1] + Prime[i + 2] + Prime[i + 3], {i, 1, 
100000} ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

what makes the difference?

Comment: I guess that coupling `ParalellSum` and `Prime` is not especially constructive in order to understand the underlying issues. `Prime` is based on `PrimePi` which uses so called Lagaris Miller Odlyzko method finding primes. This is a sophisticated algorithm using sparse caching and sieving. You should perform extensive analysis for much larger numbers. There is yet another issue related to `Prime` which  has quite different timings. You should carefully test this post [What is so special about Prime?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime)

Comment: Many parameters are automatically chosen in `Parallel...`. The argument might have a great influence on the parameters. I would suggest forcing as many parameters as possible to ensure a fair comparison. See e.g.  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55242/sudden-increase-in-timing-when-summing-over-250-entries/

Answer (score 1):

Are you interested in rapidly summing primes? or was that just an example to illustrate a `ParallelSum` question?

If you want fast methods for summing primes please see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80291/efficient-way-to-sum-all-the-primes-below-n-million-in-mathematica/80309) question and its answers.

Please note that the following is a much faster way to sum the sequence of 4 adjacent primes, the fourth example in your question.

```
With[{m = 10000}, AbsoluteTiming[
   4*ParallelSum[Prime[i], {i, 1, m + 3}] -
              3*(Prime[1] + Prime[m + 3]) -
              2*(Prime[2] + Prime[m + 2]) -
                (Prime[3] + Prime[m + 1])
   ]]
```

Comment: An example to illustrate a ParallelSum question. btw, thx for your code, quite fast.