# How to subtract the column means from each row of a matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, programming

Given a matrix, we want to subtract the mean of each column, from all entries in that column. So given this matrix:

```
 (mat = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}}) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

the mean of each column is `m = Mean[mat]`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the result should be

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This operation is called centering of observations in data science.

The best I could find using *Mathematica*, is as follows:

```
mat = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
m = Mean[mat];
(mat[[All, #]] - m[[#]]) & /@ Range@Length@m // Transpose
```

But I am not too happy with it. I think it is too complicated. Is there a simpler way to do it? I tried `Map` and `MapThread`, but I had hard time getting the syntax to work.

In MATLAB, there is a nice function called [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) which is sort of like `MapThread`. Here is how it is done in MATLAB:

```matlab
A = [1 2 3 4;5 6 7 8;9 10 11 12];
bsxfun(@minus, A, mean(A))

    -4    -4    -4    -4
     0     0     0     0
     4     4     4     4
```

It maps the function `minus`, taking one column from `A` and one element from `mean(A)`. I think it is more clear than what I have in *Mathematica*. One should be able to do this in *Mathematica* using one of the map functions more easily and clearly than what I have above.

The question is: Can the *Mathematica* solution above be improved?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
mat - ConstantArray[Mean[mat], 3]
```

or more generally:

```
mat - ConstantArray[Mean[mat], Length[mat]]
```

Answer (score 32):

It is there:

```
Standardize[mat, Mean, 1 &]
```

Comment: Here comes the winner!

Comment: @xzczd Thanks. It may be not the fastest though, it rescales by 1 anyway.

Comment: Can use Identity' instead of 1&.

Comment: Re "rescales by 1": see my answer to this Q&A.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for the investigation!

Answer (score 26):

Well, transposing, subtracting, transposing...

```
Transpose[Transpose[mat] - Mean[mat]]
```

Answer (score 13):

```
# - Mean@mat & /@ mat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: This computes the same `Mean` for each row - could be inefficient.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't mind the type of `mat` changes:

```
CircleMinus = Compile[{{a, _Real, 1}, {b, _Real, 1}}, a - b, RuntimeAttributes -> Listable]
mat⊖Mean@mat
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  -4. & -4. & -4. & -4. \\
>  0. & 0. & 0. & 0. \\
>  4. & 4. & 4. & 4. \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 8):

I was asked to post an answer based on a recently uncovered (at least, for me) undocumented function, [`` Statistics`Library`MatrixRowTranslate ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns/149507#149507), available in V10 and later.  My feeling is that, at heart, it is essentially the same as [Kuba's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103554/4999), which I will use this answer to explain.  I will also shed some further light on [Kuba's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103527/best-way-to-emulate-matlabs-bsxfun-using-map-and-similar-functions#comment281165_103554).

First, the function `` Statistics`Library`MatrixRowTranslate `` modifies the matrix in place, which is uncharacteristic of *Mathematica*.  Here is a typical usage applied to the OP's problem:

```
mat = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
Module[{res = mat},
  Statistics`Library`MatrixRowTranslate[res, -Mean[res]];
  res] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In V11 (but not in V10, though the functionality exists), Kuba's [`Standardize[mat, Mean, 1 &]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Standardize.html) uses this call to shift `mat` by the mean, but it also rescales by the second function, which seems inefficient for the problem at hand.  However, it turns out that rescaling by `constant &` is a special case that is implemented by dividing the translated matrix by `constant`.  In case you didn't know, multiplying by `1` (not `1.`) is also a special case, which the comparison below will show.  Dividing by `1` in normal *Mathematica* means multiplying by the reciprocal `Power[1, -1]` and takes roughly twice as long as multiplication, [unless you use `Divide`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40927/why-are-numeric-division-and-subtraction-not-handled-better-in-mathematica).

```
SeedRandom[0];
data = RandomReal[{0, 50}, {1*^7, 2}];
1*data; // RepeatedTiming
data/1; // RepeatedTiming
Divide[data, 1]; // RepeatedTiming
1.*data; // RepeatedTiming
data/2; // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {3.01*10^-7, Null}
  {5.2*10^-7, Null}
  {3.8*10^-7, Null}
  {0.063, Null}
  {0.062, Null}
*)
```

So we should expect that the rescaling by `1 &` in Kuba's answer to add a negligible amount of time to the overall time of the operation in V11:

```
mrt = Module[{res = data},
    Statistics`Library`MatrixRowTranslate[res, -Mean[res]];
    res]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.139, Null}  *)

st = Standardize[data, Mean, 1 &]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.139, Null}  *)

mrt == st     (* check *)
(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Thanks, good addition to this Q&A, especially for v10 users like me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Even though I noticed the difference in V10, I was really slow to recognize its significance.  Thanks for prodding me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard sorry for pinging you here, but I was not sure I could reach you in chat. I wanted to suggest changing the title of the question to "How to subtract the column means from each row of a matrix?". I suppose it could be argued that the accepted answer kind of implements `bsxfun` (see also [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149691/4330)), but I feel for example the `Standardize` answer should also be captured by the title, especially considering that another question was closed as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @Jacob I think that would be a good change.  "bsxfun" will still appear in the body should anyone explicitly search for that.  For other (non-MATLAB) users your title seems far more descriptive.

Answer (score 4):

```
mat = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
Transpose[Map[# - Mean[#] &, Transpose[mat]]]
```

which gives you

```
{{-4, -4, -4, -4}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {4, 4, 4, 4}}
```

Answer (score 4):

You might think of transposing your data.  MATLAB naturally has the column as the basic subunit of the matrix, while Mathematica has the row.

Defining

```
(mat = Transpose[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 
 12}}]) // MatrixForm
```

the (transpose) of the desired result is then

```
mat - Mean /@ mat // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is something a bit closer to the Matlab syntax

```
mat1=Partition[Range@12,4];
mat2 = ConstantArray[Mean[mat1], Length[mat1]];
binaryFunction = #1 - #2 &;

MapThread[binaryFunction, {mat1,mat2}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
TranslationTransform[- Mean @ mat] @ mat
```

> ```
> {{-4, -4, -4, -4}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {4, 4, 4, 4}}
> ```

Roughly comparable to `Standardize` in speed.

In versions 13.1.0+, you can also use [`Threaded`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Threaded.html):

```
mat - Threaded @ Mean @ mat
```

> ```
> {{-4, -4, -4, -4}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {4, 4, 4, 4}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Mike's answer (the accepted one), almost implements `bsxfun`, taking listability for granted, like this

```
bsxfunListable[listableFu_, mat_, vec_] :=
 listableFu[mat, ConstantArray[vec, Length@mat]];

bsxfun[Subtract, mat, Mean@mat]
```

We can generalise the function like this

```
bsxfun[fu_, mat_, vec_] :=
 Thread @@ {Unevaluated @@ 
    fu @@@ Hold@Evaluate@{mat, ConstantArray[vec, Length@mat]}}

bsxfun[Subtract, mat, Mean@mat]
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition:

```
Inner[Subtract, mat, Mean[mat],List]

(* {
    {-4, -4, -4, -4}, 
    {0,   0,  0,  0}, 
    {4,   4,  4,  4}
   }  *)
```

```
Inner[Subtract, mat, {a,b,c,d},List]

(* {
    {1 - a,  2 - b,  3 - c,  4 - d}, 
    {5 - a,  6 - b,  7 - c,  8 - d}, 
    {9 - a, 10 - b, 11 - c, 12 - d}
   }  *)
```