# Fast way to subtract the mean from a dataset

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have a dataset, say:

```
data = 
  {{10, 8.04}, {8, 6.95}, {13, 7.58}, {9, 8.81}, {11, 8.33}, {14, 9.96}, 
   {6, 7.24}, {4, 4.26}, {12, 10.84}, {7, 4.82}, {5, 5.68}}
```

and I want to subtract the mean from it, producing:

> ```
> correcteddata = 
>   {{1, 0.539091}, {-1, -0.550909}, {4, 0.0790909}, {0, 1.30909}, {2, 0.829091}, 
>    {5, 2.45909}, {-3, -0.260909}, {-5, -3.24091}, {3, 3.33909}, {-2, -2.68091}, 
>    {-4, -1.82091}}
> ```

However, I'm looking to do this on a much larger data-set as efficiently as possible.

I've gone through several attempts:

This was very slow, but simple:

```
correcteddata = # - Mean[data] & /@ data
```

This was significantly faster, but involves adding another variable:

```
m = Mean[data];
correcteddata = # - m & /@ data
```

The fastest/best I've found so far is this:

```
correcteddata = Transpose[# - Mean /@ # &[Transpose[data]]]
```

But I'm wondering if there is something better.

Comment: I think the notation of the question is a bit confusing. You do not have a dataset ... you have sample bivariate $(X_i,Y_i)$ data. And rather than the stated desire to '`subtract the mean from it`, you wish to subtract the sample _means_ from the data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do this:

```
Standardize[data, Mean, 1 &]
```

Here are the timings for comparison, with `f1` and `f2` as defined in Mr.Wizard's answer:

```
big = RandomReal[{0, 50}, {1*^7, 2}];

f1[big] // RepeatedTiming // First
f2[big] // RepeatedTiming // First
Standardize[big, Mean, 1 &] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.274
>
> 0.232
>
> 0.12

Comment: What version and platform are you using?  In 10.1 under Windows this is much slower than either `f1` or `f2` in my post at 0.85 seconds on the same test.

Comment: Strange - on my Mac with MMA 11.0.1 my answer is twice as fast as yours...

Comment: On the same `big` data?  If so I guess this function received a needed upgrade.

Comment: Yes, I added the timings with your method.

Answer (score 11):

This is a modest improvement on your code:

```
f2[data_] := (data\[Transpose] - Mean[data])\[Transpose]
```

With your code as a function `f1` for reference:

```
f1[data_] := Transpose[# - Mean /@ # &[Transpose[data]]]
```

***And now with Simon Woods's `f3` calling the internal function used by `Standardize` in v11:***

```
f3[data_] := 
  Module[{a = data}, Statistics`Library`MatrixRowTranslate[a, -Mean[a]]; a]
```

Timings:

```
big = RandomReal[{0, 50}, {1*^7, 2}];

f1[big] // RepeatedTiming // First
f2[big] // RepeatedTiming // First
f3[big] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.193
>
> 0.15
>
> 0.0936
> ```

```
f1[big] === f2[big] === f3[big]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

---

In *Mathematica* 10.1 under Windows x64 [`Standardize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Standardize.html) performs rather poorly.  I get:

```
Standardize[big, Mean, 1 &] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.852
> ```

I am curious to know if this is version or platform dependent, or perhaps both.

Comment: In V10.4.1 and V9.0, `Standardize` took `1.6` sec and in `V11.1.1` it took `0.14` sec.

Comment: Try ``f3[data_] := Block[{a = data}, Statistics`Library`MatrixRowTranslate[a, -Mean[data]]; a]`` - this is what Standardize does in 11.1.1

Comment: @Simon Thanks, that gives the performance one would have anticipated for a built-in!  (I used `Module` as I feel that is appropriate.)

Comment: @Simon beat me to it. I figured that out, which led to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns/149507#149507), but haven't had time to come back here.

Comment: @Michael would you please use that to answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103527/121 ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard [Done.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103527/best-way-to-emulate-matlabs-bsxfun-using-map-and-similar-functions/149603#149603) -- Thanks.