# FullForm[1. - (0.3 + 0.4)] gives 0.30000000000000004`

Tags: warning-messages, precision-and-accuracy

I had a serious error propagation in my computations (Mathematica 10.4.1 Windows 64 bit). After some investigation, I realized the problem comes from something like this: FullForm[1. - (0.3 + 0.4)] gives 0.30000000000000004`.

Is it a bug? How to fix it?

Comment: No, it is not a bug. It's called floating point numbers. A number like `0.3` cannot be represented exactly by a binary floating point number. For example, displaying the machine precision number `0.3` as floating point number with higher precision with `FullForm[SetPrecision[0.3, 20]]` will return ``0.29999999999999998889776975374843459576`20.``.

Comment: This one is similar and the answer fits here well: [What is special about 70.329862](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63317/5478), this is closely related too: [104032](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104032/5478)

Comment: One fix is to use rational numberts: 1-(3/10+4/10)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about machine precision representation of base 10 values in binary, not specific to Mathematica

Comment: @DanielLichtblau so are many similar questions, e.g. both I linked above. Do you agree with closing it as a duplicate instead or have I missed the point here?

Comment: I'm fine with calling it a duplicate. In most cases, as best I recall, the poster is unaware of the `FullForm` and does not realize there are nonzero decimal digits involved.