# Eliminating elements from sublists under a global condition

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

Consider the following [list](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cd1402ed2201e712347e) of `4215` sublists (note that the file as displayed at github is truncated, but there is a link to the full version). Each of the `4215` sublists contain one or more `cst[i]` entries for some integer `i`. I would like to set to zero / remove the maximum amount of different `cst[i]` while still maintaining at least one `cst[i]` in each of the `4215` sublists. In particular, I need to know which of the `cst[i]` are being dropped in the process. How should I be going about finding this list of `cst[i]` efficiently?

EDIT:

I was asked in the comments to illustrate my problem on a simple example. Consider the following toy list:

```
myList= {{cst[1],cst[2],cst[3]},{cst[1]},{cst[2],cst[3]}}
```

This toy example list contains three sublists. Now, the task is to drop a maximum amount of `cst[i]` such that each of the sublists still contains at least one `cst[i]`. By direct inspection we see that the second sublist consists of the single element `cst[1]`, so that `cst[1]` definitely cannot be removed. The first and the second sublists have more entries though, and we see that either `cst[2]` or `cst[3]` can be dropped (but not both) in order to still satisfy the condition. Therefore the output might look like

```
WhichCanBeDropped[myList]
```

> `{cst[2]}`

Or, it could look like

```
WhichCanBeDropped[myList]
```

> `{cst[3]}`

Both results would be considered equivalent.

EDIT2:

Another case of interest would be a list with sublists containing 2 or more elements `cst[i]`. i.e.

```
myList= {{cst[1],cst[2],cst[3]},{cst[1],cst[4]},{cst[2],cst[3],cst[4]}}
```

Now we want to remove a maximum amount of elements `cst[i]` such that each sublist still contains at least two `cst[i]` entries. In the above new toy list the answer would again be that `cst[2]` xor `cst[3]` can be dropped.

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates[]`?  Can you give a small, representative sample of the data that illustrates your problem?

Comment: I added a toy example to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Generalization

Your second example is easy to accommodate, and while I'm at it I'll wrap up my code as reusable functions.  First a function to convert your data to a binary matrix.  I shall assume that the input to the function will be e.g. `{{1, 2, 3}, {1}, {2, 3}}` but I include two external methods to strip the `cst` from your lists.

```
toArray[dat_: {{__Integer} ..}] /; Min[dat] > 0 :=
  Module[{m},
    m = ConstantArray[0, {Max @ dat, Length @ dat}];
    MapIndexed[(m[[##]] = 1) &, dat];
    m
  ]
```

Applied to your first input:

```
myList1 = {{cst[1], cst[2], cst[3]}, {cst[1]}, {cst[2], cst[3]}};

myList1[[All, All, 1]] // toArray // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

The question is then which rows can we delete without causing any columns to total a number below a specified value.  To speed the test I will [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) the array (by column) first, then subtract each row from that total.  The minimum value is compared against the reference `n` and positions are found using fast numeric operations [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html) and [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html).

```
canBeDropped[m_?MatrixQ, n : _Integer?Positive : 1] :=
  With[{tot = Total[m]},
    Map[Min[tot ~Subtract~ #] &, m] - n //
      UnitStep // SparseArray[#]["AdjacencyLists"] &
  ]
```

The complete process for your first example:

```
myList1[[All, All, 1]] // toArray // canBeDropped
```

> ```
> {2, 3}
> ```

And for your second:

```
myList2 = {{cst[1],cst[2],cst[3]},{cst[1],cst[4]},{cst[2],cst[3],cst[4]}};

toArray[myList2 /. cst -> Identity] ~canBeDropped~ 2
```

> ```
> {2, 3}
> ```

Observe that `/. cst -> Identity` is another way to prepare your data for `toArray`.  Depending on your needs you may also wish to look at [`ArrayComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayComponents.html) for this task, though be sure you understand what it is doing before you adopt it.

Comment: Alternatively: `Position[Reverse[Subsets[sa, {2}]], m_?MatrixQ /; Positive[Times @@ Total[m]]]`.

Comment: @J.M. I believe I thought of a more efficient way to perform that operation; see the update.  (And tell me if I goofed.)

Comment: Would've used `% // Position[_?Positive]` myself. ;)

Comment: @J.M. That was my [starting point.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/107646/1)  I *think* `// Sign // Position[1]` will be faster, and the OP said "efficiently" so that's what I went with.

Comment: Wow this is a great sneaky way to do it! Wonder if it can be generalized to allow for at least two entries to be non-zero? (In which case we start with all sublists containing at least two entries to begin with, of course.)

Comment: @Kagaratsch Glad I could help. :-)  If you edit the question to include an example of the generalization you would like I'll try to address it.

Comment: I edited the question to outline the other case.

Comment: Thank you again! The code is also much more readable now.

Comment: @Kagaratsch You are welcome.  I replaced my code for `toArray` as `SparseArray` proved counterproductive here.  I also added a note about `ArrayComponents` which is a function that may interest you.  And just now I used long form `Subtract` in `canBeDropped` as [it is faster.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40927/121)