# conditions in Select

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list of lists that looks something like -

```
  data= {{920.093, 1135., 110.45, 1135., 1135.19, 1138.13, 920.093,850.453, 
  920.093, 921.905, 991.545, 859.285, 983.714, 1133.21, 
  1135.8}, {1509.96, 1907.41, 114.108, 1907.41, 1907.51, 1909.41, 
  1509.96, 1439.94, 1509.96, 1511.06, 1581.07, 1448.6, 1573.03, 
  1906.34, 1907.89}, ...}
```

I want to select only those lists where 8th element is always smaller than all the other elements of the list. I tried using-

```
   data1=Select[data,#[[1]]>#[[8]]&&#[[2]]>#[[8]]&&#[[4]]>#[[8]]...&]
```

But It looks quite stupid. Is there any other minimal way to impose this condition?

Comment: `Select[data, #[[8]] == Min[#] &]`?

Comment: @J.M. That means smaller or equal, but OP's code checks if element 8 is strictly smaller than all the other elements.

Comment: Select is very slow. Use Cases[] instead: Cases[data, c_/;c[[8]]<Min@Delete[c,8],1]. Though the Pick[] solution below is by far the fastest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could for example use

```
res1 = Select[
 data,
 Function[{list}, AllTrue[Drop[list, {8}], list[[8]] < # &]]
 ]
```

but this is not the fastest way to do it in *Mathematica*. This might be perform better:

```
{{eigth}, rest} = TakeDrop[Transpose[data], {8}];
sel = Total /@ Transpose@UnitStep[ConstantArray[eigth, Length[rest]] - rest];
res2 = Pick[data, sel, 0];
```

The result is the same:

```
res1 == res2
```

> `True`

Comment: You may be interested in the tuned version of your second method that I posted below. (+1 of course, as if I need to say it)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Nice, +1

Comment: @C.E. What can be done if we want to exclude certain elements from the less than condition? For e.g- I want every element to be smaller than 8th element except 2nd one. 2nd element can have any value.

Comment: @solphy Then you use `Drop` again on `#` and `rest` respectively.

Answer (score 7):

A straightforward solution (and correction of J. M.'s comment code):

```
SeedRandom[0]
data = RandomInteger[9, {100, 10}];

Select[data, #[[8]] < Min @ Drop[#, {8}] &]
```

> ```
> {{3, 9, 4, 7, 2, 1, 2, 0, 7, 8},
>  {9, 5, 9, 9, 3, 6, 6, 1, 3, 3},
>  {3, 5, 2, 2, 6, 8, 9, 1, 3, 7},
>  {9, 6, 7, 8, 8, 7, 9, 1, 7, 6}}
> ```

This is twice as fast as C. E.'s [`AllTrue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AllTrue.html) code:

```
data = RandomInteger[9, {10000, 15}];

Select[data, Function[{list}, AllTrue[Drop[list, {8}], list[[8]] < # &]]] // 
  Length // RepeatedTiming

Select[data, #[[8]] < Min @ Drop[#, {8}]] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.045, 273}
>
> {0.021, 273}
> ```

It is still and order of magnitude behind his [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) method however.  Here is a tuned version of that code that can be more than twice as fast.

*Now faster and cleaner after reading LLlAMnYP's answer and recognizing a simplification.*

```
select[data_, n_] := (
   Subtract[data[[All, n]], data]
     // UnitStep
     // Total[#, {2}] &
     // Pick[data, #, 1] &
 )

SeedRandom[0]
data = RandomInteger[9, {1*^6, 15}];

select[data, 8] // Length // RepeatedTiming

(* his code *)  // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.141, 28205}
>
> {0.302, 28205}
> ```

Methods include explicit `Subtract`; reference:

- [Why are numeric division and subtraction not handled better in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40927/121)

Comment: Why not `Delete[]` instead of `Drop[]`?

Comment: @J.M. I tried both; `Drop` tested faster for me in v10.1 on packed Integers.

Comment: I *believe*, the `target = td[[ Table[n, {Length @ rest}] ]];` allowed `Subtract[target, rest]` to be faster in the previous version of the answer. However the same approach within `Compile` only slows things down for me.

Comment: By the way, what was the purpose of `List @@ (Transpose[data])` in the previous function?

Comment: @J.M. amusingly, on 10.2 inside `Compile` my first attempt actually found `Delete` to be faster.

Answer (score 4):

Even though there is already an accepted answer, the problem at hand lends itself well to a compiled approach for performance gains.

```
compiledSelect =
 Compile[{{a, _Integer, 2}},
  Total[Transpose[UnitStep[-a + a[[1 ;; -1, 8]]]]],
  CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True, "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"]
selectLL[data_] := Pick[data, compiledSelect[data], 1]
```

Comparing this to Mr.Wizard's best solution:

```
data = RandomInteger[9, {1*^6, 15}];
selectLL[data] == select[data, 8]
selectLL[data] // Length // RepeatedTiming
select[data, 8] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> True
> {0.212, 27950}
> {0.220, 27950}
> ```

It has a very marginal edge of a few percent in speed. In essence, this is a sort of refactoring of Mr.Wizard's code, minimizing the necessary manipulations, but only `Compile` lets it be faster.

**EDIT**
After carefully considering Mr.Wizard's reference I included an explicit `Subtract` as well:

```
compiledSelect2 =
 Compile[{{a, _Integer, 2}},
  Total[Transpose[UnitStep[Subtract[a[[1 ;; -1, 8]], a]]]]
  , CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True, 
  "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"]
selectLL2[data_] := Pick[data, compiledSelect2[data], 1]
```

Now including performance tests for Mr.Wizard's simplified function (which I call `select2` here). I also leave the original function (see his edit history) for comparison purposes.

```
data = RandomInteger[9, {1*^6, 15}];
selectLL[data] == select[data, 8] == select2[data, 8] == selectLL2[data]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Benchmarking with repeatedly new data:

```
(Table[data = RandomInteger[9, {1*^6, 15}];
 {selectLL[data] // Length // RepeatedTiming // First,
  selectLL2[data] // Length // RepeatedTiming // First,
  select[data, 8] // Length // RepeatedTiming // First,
  select2[data, 8] // Length // RepeatedTiming // First}, {10}]
    // Transpose
    // Map[Append[#, Mean@#] &]
    // Prepend[#, Range[10]~Join~{"Avg."}] & 
    // Transpose 
    // Join[{{"N.", "selectLL", "selectLL2", "select", "select2"}}, #] &
    // Grid
```

> [image]

All the functions used in our routines are certainly implemented in low-level code where `Compile` can hardly give much of an edge. As we see, a compiled `//Transpose//Total` loses out to the uncompiled `Total[..., {2}]`.

A quick shot at "improving" (maybe in performance, certainly not in readability) Mr.W's code by removing all explicit `Function`s:

```
select3[data_, n_] :=
 Pick[data, Total[Subtract[data[[All, n]], data] // UnitStep, {2}], 1]
Table[data = RandomInteger[9, {1*^6, 15}]; 
 select3[data, 8] // Length // RepeatedTiming // First, {10}]
```

> ```
> {0.195, 0.194, 0.194, 0.195, 0.194, 0.194, 0.194, 0.195, 0.195, 0.194}
> ```

Very marginally better, probably not statistically significant.

**TODO:**
Were the input transposed, could the compiled function be more efficient?

*After some tests, it doesn't look that way.*

**EDIT:**
I managed to find a fully compiled version that performs on par with the other solutions. Still not as fast as `select2` though.

```
compiledSelect3 = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 2}},
  a[[
    Flatten@
      Position[
        Total[
          Transpose[
            UnitStep[Subtract[a[[All, 8]], a]]
          ]
        ], 
        1
      ]
    ]]
  , CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True, 
  "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"]
```

Head-to-head with `select2`:

```
Table[data = RandomInteger[9, {1*^6, 15}];
  (compiledSelect3[data] // RepeatedTiming // First) -
    (select2[data, 8] // RepeatedTiming // First), {10}]
Mean@%
```

> ```
> {0.003, 0.004, 0.008, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006, 0.005, 0.006, 0.006, 0.*10^-3}
> 0.006
> ```

3% slower. Close, but no cigar.

Comment: From this answer I see that all that faff with `Drop` and `Table` I used was counterproductive.  I shall update my answer with a simpler form.  Thank you, and +1 for inspiration.  (Please consider updating your timings after my edit.)

Comment: @Mr.W I was really surprised that your approach was actually slowed down when I tried to simplify it to that what I tried. I'll be researching that tomorrow and see what happens to the timings.

Comment: Did you use an explicit (verbatim) `Subtract` in what you tried?

Comment: @Mr.W No, your answer seemed conceptually similar to mine, so I just copied my part of the code verbatim; unfortunately I didn't have time to dig deeper.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard added the benchmarks, our answers seem to converge to each other. As I mentioned, your previous code had a lot of overhead and still it was competitive. I think there is something to be borrowed from there, and the reference you edited out.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure I understand *I think there is something to be borrowed from there, and the reference you edited out.*  Do you feel that I removed something from my answer I should not have?  Should I restore the intermediate version and append the last version as `select2`?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
Pick[data, Negative[data[[All, 8]] - Min /@ Drop[data, 0, {8}]]]
```